# Add separate div after a form

Tags: forms, blocks, hooks

All I want to do is add a new `<div>`, ideally just *after* a `<form>` element.  I have a self-written module that generates a payment form, using some routing, like this:

```
mymodule.applications.payment_form:
  path: '/payment/{submission}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\PaymentForm'
    _title_callback: '\Drupal\mymodule\Form\PaymentForm::getTitle'
  requirements:
    _role: 'authenticated'
    _custom_access: 'Drupal\mymodule\Form\PaymentForm::access'
  options:
    parameters:
      submission:
        type: entity:webform_submission
```

The PaymentForm class has a standard buildForm() method, and it's easy to add render arrays to the $form build form elements and other decoration etc. But those are all *within* the `<form>` tag.

The payment form is displayed in the main page content block.

I've been trying is **HOOK_preprocess_HTML** in my `mymodule.module` file and looking at *$vars*.

$vars['page'] contains the various regions: sidebar_first, content, secondary_menu etc.

$vars['page']['content'] consists of:

```
'mysite_page_title' => array(13)
'mysite_local_tasks' => array(3)
'mysite_help' => array(3)
'mysite_local_actions' => array(3)
'mysite_content' => array(12)
'#sorted' => boolTRUE
'#theme_wrappers' => array(1)
'#region' => string(7) "content"
```

`mysite_content` is a block - and I can't see how I can modify it from here...

I've also tried **HOOK_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter**, which in this case is system_main_block (for the page content).

*function mymodule_block_view_system_main_block_alter* gives me a $build array with a *#block* element, but I don't see how I can find the `<form>` elements in there either and place something afterwards…

Anything else I can do?

Comment: Sounds like you could create a controller and then change your routing to point to that. Then that controller could retrieve the form render array and then display it along with whatever else renderable items you'd like to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be hundreds of ways to add this markup in Drupal. The two simplest that came to my mind are:

1) Add a suffix to the form tag in form build or form alter:

```
$form['#suffix'] = '<div>Suffix to form</div>';
```

2) or add the markup in a form.html.twig below the form tag:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation for a 'form' element.
 *
 * Available variables
 * - attributes: A list of HTML attributes for the wrapper element.
 * - children: The child elements of the form.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_form()
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}
<form{{ attributes }}>
  {{ children }}
</form>

<div>
  A div container after the form
</div>
```

For the second solution you might also need to add a theme name suggestion.

Comment: Thanks - I had considered whether to override a template, but hadn't realised #suffix would work in this context…